# Can't call value from SQL using $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, session

Sorry, I'm just beginner in PHP MySQL and I have problem getting the condition that I want.

I'm fetching *SQL* value using **$_SESSION** it was error and looks like it can't fetch the value.

**Here is my code on my top section:**

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])) 
    { 
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
?>
```

**Here is my code with if else condition** in my top bar, although it get the *'agentFname'* and *'agentLname'* value from database but it can't get the value of *'user_type'* is column from database.

```
 <img src="images/img.jpg" alt="">

  <?php

         if($_SESSION['user_type'] == 'Team Leader')
         {
               echo "Team Leader, ".' '.$userRow['agentFname'].' '.$userRow['agentLname'];
         } 
         else 
         {
               echo "Agent, ".' '.$userRow['agentFname'].' '.$userRow['agentLname'];
         }

  ?>

  <span class=" fa fa-angle-down"></span>
```

**Here is the output with error, which this user is Admin type**

[image: Error]

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you setting `$_SESSION['user_type']`?

Comment: where di you set this session var `$_SESSION['user_type']`??

Comment: You are not set value of **$_SESSION['user_type']**

Comment: 'user_type' is a  column in database named 'accounts'

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comment , user_type is a field in table .. so use like this-

```
 if($userRow['user_type'] == 'Team Leader')
             {
                   echo "Team Leader, ".' '
                        .$userRow['agentFname'].' '.$userRow['agentLname'];
             }
```

Comment: You clear to me that my $userRow = $_SESSION.  Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Use php isset() function for remove this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
//your condition
}
```

or set value of $_SESSION['user_type'] before use

Comment: May I know how to set the value before I use?

Comment: Problem Solved, Thanks!